# Django Fulltext search is very slow how to make it fast?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, full-text-search

I possess an extensive database of products and aim to implement full-text search functionality to enable users to easily search for products. I've employed SearchVector with Postgres for this purpose; however, the performance is quite sluggish. Despite attempting to enhance speed through indexing, it hasn't yielded the desired results. Below is a snippet of the code I've been working with.

```
models.py

class Product(models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(BrandName,related_name="brand_products",  on_delete=models.CASCADE,db_index = True)
    item_name_title = models.CharField(max_length=10000, db_index = True,)
    product_description = models.TextField(db_index = True,)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            GinIndex(fields=['search_vector']),
        ]


Views.py

search = request.GET.get('search')
search_vector = SearchVector(
                'product__mob_sku',
                'product__item_name_title',
                'product__product_description',
                'product__brand__brand_name',

                )

query = SearchQuery(search)
vendor_products = VendorProducts.objects.annotate(
                rank = (SearchRank(search_vector , query))
                ).filter(rank__gte=0.001).select_related(
                    'vendor', 'product').prefetch_related(
                        'product__product_images', 'product__brand').exclude(
                vendor__vendor_name = "ALL_123").order_by('-rank')
```

Comment: As far as I know indexing columns will not index lexemes, but probably even if that is the case, it would still do a linear search. Often a database for text matching like elastic search is used for that that will split text into lexemes, etc. to make retrieval faster than linear scanning.

Comment: Should I add Elastic search? Or there is an alternative solution which I can use

Comment: Please check "Performance considerations" section here: https://medium.com/@nandagopal05/django-full-text-search-with-postgresql-f063aaf34e35

Answer (score 0):

Your indexes aren't being used, as your search is spanning multiple models. You really need to get all those related fields into a big search index.

If you're willing to use a 3rd-party Django app, `django-watson` supports this:

https://github.com/etianen/django-watson/wiki/registering-models#searching-across-related-models

(I wrote `django-watson` a long while ago, but it's still maintained!)

Comment: Will it handle? wrong spellings and other search scenarios?

Comment: It's backed by whatever full text search the database provides. For postgres, this means some reasonable word stemming and stopword removal: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html . For other database backends, it's less feature-complete. https://github.com/etianen/django-watson/wiki/Database-support. It's certainly not in the league of a dedicated search service like Elastic search

Comment: It not working exactly it should lets take an example I have product named Bharathi Cement Portland Pozzolana Cement (PPC), 50 kgs, Grey

Now when user is searching for PPC 50 kgs its working
but when user is searching for PPC 50kgs its not working because this string don't have space in between 50kgs.
How to handle this???

Comment: That's a limitation of database full text search, and there's not a lot you can do. It's convenient and pretty performant, but it's not at the level of a dedicated search service.

Comment: Then how to handle this kind of situation. Also if user types any wrong spelling then also I need to show the recommended products

Comment: Your original question asked how to speed up your query using indexing. django-watson, the suggested search package, will do exactly that. The capabilities you're talking about now are beyond what Django or django-watson fulltext search can provide, and also a different question!